# Using %ksappend from main kickstart file from usb device, what is the correct path?

Tags: usb, path, kickstart, append

I'm using kickstart for the installation of a Fedora system.
I separated some steps of the installation in some kickstart files, so they can be easily reused. For example, the section about partitioning is in one file, the packages to be installed in another one. The needed files are put together in the main ks file using **%ksappend**, because, unlike %include, it is parsed before **%pre**. This is needed because the appended files can contain %pre sections themselves.

When installing over the network, everything goes well since the append path is an "absolute" url (e.g. %ksappend http://192.168.0.39/partitioning_lvm.ks). I was wondering what path should I use if the kickstart installation tree is placed on a usb device.

I guess, if using %include, I could mount the device in %pre in a known location before including the files (in /tmp for example). In this case, however is not possible because %ksappend, as said before, is parsed before %pre.

Any ideas?